# Rails Validator Skip inclusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a class with the following validators:

```
fields field:name 'field_name',

requires :field_name,

validates :field_name, inclusion: { in: %w(cat dog fish),
                       message: "%{value} is not a valid field_name"
```

So I instantiated this class with field_name `null` and I got two validation errors:

1. field_name cannot be `null` (so the `requires` fails as expected)
2. `null` is not a valid field name

Is there a way that I can set up these validators for that if field_name is null, it will skip the second check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
validates :field_name, inclusion: { in: %w(cat dog fish) },
                       message: "%{value} is not a valid field_name",
                       unless: -> { field_name.nil? }
```

If you are using ActiveSupport (which you are if you're using Rails), you can also use `.blank?` instead of `.nil?` to also treat empty arrays and hashes, and strings with only whitespace as empty.

Comment: Copied the first line from your question. :)